# Issue with Angular version in rating

Tags: angularjs

I 'm trying to use Angular rating from this http://plnkr.co/edit/gZHBqHjg35f5E9M2Pvib?p=preview

Here is my Angular code.

```
var ProfileApp = angular.module('ProfileApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
ProfileApp.controller('getprofile', function($scope, $http) {
//Some codes are here

})
 ProfileApp.controller('RatingDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.myRate = 0;
      $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log($scope.percent); //null
      }
      $scope.rate = 1;
      $scope.max = 5;
      $scope.isReadonly = false;
      $scope.percent = 20;
      $scope.hoveringOver = function(value, object) {
        console.log('hoveringOver', value);
        $scope.overStar = value;
        $scope.percent = (100 * $scope.overStar) / $scope.max;
      };
      $scope.hoveringLeave = function(rate) {
        console.log('hoveringLeave', $scope.rate);
        $scope.percent = (100 * $scope.rate) / $scope.max;
      };
    });
```

And here is the html code.

```
<div ng-controller="RatingDemoCtrl" class="well well-small">
    <form class="Scroller-Container" ng-submit="submit()"></form>
    <rating value="rate" max="max" readonly="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="hoveringLeave(rate)"></rating>
    <span class="badge" ng-class="{'badge-warning': percent<30, 'badge-info': percent>=30 && percent<70, 'badge-success': percent>=70}" ng-show="overStar && !isReadonly">{{percent}}%</span>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <pre>{{percent}}</pre>

  </div>
```

Unfortunately, I am getting error:

> angular.min.js:101 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=r%20in%20range&p1=object%3A10&p2=%7B%22stateOn%22%3Anull%2C%22stateOff%22%3Anull%7D

In Plunker there is no error, but when I use the code I am getting above error. No star is visible.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I am using the above versions and thats the reason stars are not visible.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vQ9Odm1dAAo8ZJOGHlB7

Here is plunker.

Comment: the code you provided doesn't have `ng-repeat`, so it's not enough to know what's causing the error. Is the code in Pulnker exactly as the one you're running locally?

Comment: yes, ui.bootstrap is might contain ng-repeat.

Comment: From the [UI-Bootstrap documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#bootstrap-requirements),  UI Bootstrap requires Bootstrap CSS version 3.x or higher and it has been tested with Bootstrap CSS 3.3.6.
UI Bootstrap 0.8 is the last version that supports Bootstrap CSS 2.3.x.   I [forked your last plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KZIRERVruPzZS2Hc3pkG?p=preview) and changed to the latest 4.0.0 Bootstrap CSS, and it works fine.  If you **must** use this version of Bootstrap CSS, you will either need to downgrade ui-bootstrap or write your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error as that version of UI bootstrap and Angular 1.3.1 not compatible

what I did, went to https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
scroll to RATING,
click "Edit in plunker",
saved Plunker for you plnkr.co/edit/xNoNfMCKs0HcOcJMhkK2

adopt code for your needs and try latest Angular 1.x, or downgrade to whatever you need in Plunker and ask here with url to that if you got any issues

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped me a lot. But the issue still persists. Seems like the issue with Angular version. I am updating the question with a fiddle.